# Selenium and Chrome error: --ignore-certificate-errors

Tags: google-chrome, selenium

I'm trying to do some tests with selenium and it seems that with Firefox everything works correctly but when the test try to open Chrome browser it shows the above error, --ignore-certificate-errors.

The log info says:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

### Test set: com.myproject.login.LoginOK

Tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 18.156 sec <<< FAILURE! - in com.myproject.login.LoginOK
testLoginChromeOK on testLoginChromeOK(com.myproject.login.LoginOK)(com.myproject.login.LoginOK)  Time elapsed: 1.926 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 
unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"19659.1","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
  (Session info: chrome=56.0.2924.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248304,platform=Linux 3.16.0-38-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 144 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:49:13 -0700'
System info: host: 'Acer', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.16.0-38-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, chrome={userDataDir=/tmp/.com.google.Chrome.ifVATg}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=56.0.2924.87, platform=LINUX, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 0534e4dd8d67942dbc415812d7b4b15d
    at com.myproject.login.LoginOK.testLoginChromeOK(LoginOK.java:64)

Could someone give me a hint? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see the following:

> Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248304

It seems your are using an outdated chromedriver and it might not be compatible with your current chrome version (chrome 56).

[Latest version changelog](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.27/notes.txt) shows "Supports Chrome v54-56", so I think you should [download latest version of chromedriver](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.27/) and then configure selenium to use that latest version.

Comment: Really chrome..  driver 2.27 is newer than driver 2.9.   Very good naming strategy... not..  Thanks for this answer finally realised I was using an old driver!

Comment: The standard naming convention is using a major.minor format, so that means 2.27 is really the 27th 'version'. 2.9 is the 9th 'version', thus making 2.27 a rightly newer version of the driver than 2.9.